# Create a package or a function that behaves as a method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, npm

I would like to create an npm package for common functions that I use and are not part of javascript , but I dont know how can I create them to use them as methods, let me explain myself

For example I want to use a function like

```
let reverseString = (string) => string.split('').reverse().join('');
```

For sure I could use it like `reverseString(''somethinghere')`

But I would like to use it like `'somethinghere'.reverseString()`

Thank you so much in advance.....

Comment: No need to create a module, just use `module.exports`/`require()` or `import`/`export` (i.e. put the functions in a .js file, export them in there, then import the file elsewhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh. Its not at all related to npm package. You are talking about JS prototypes. Basically you want to add custom function in String class. Not a good idea to do but still if you want you can do

```
String.prototype.reverseString = function (str) {
    return str.split('').reverse().join('');
  }
```

Comment: @Daniel 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/14034242/4221475

Answer (score 0):

Create a .js file with your method:

```
module.exports = {
  reverseString: (string) => string.split('').reverse().join('')
}
```

Then elsewhere, use it with `require()`

```
const somethinghere = require('myfile.js')

somethinghere.reverseString('hello')
```